# how do you add a condition to a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

if i have this code today to find out a sum total using LINQ:

```
return (MyArray.Sum(r => r.Trips);
```

and i want to only include itms **where r.CanDrive == true**.

can you add a condition into a single linke lambda expression?  how would you do this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could chain two bits of LINQ together like so:

```
return MyArray.Where(r => r.CanDrive).Sum(r => r.Trips);
```

Comment: What's with the leading parenthesis?

Comment: Your dialing wand is in the post :)

Answer (score 11):

David's answer is entirely correct, but another alternative might be to use a conditional operator:

```
return MyArray.Sum(r => r.CanDrive ? r.Trips : 0);
```

I would personally use the `Where` form, but I thought I'd present an alternative...

(Yet another alternative would be to create your own `Sum` method which took both a predicate and a projection, but I think that's over the top.)